# C# Process.Start() - target app can't find file

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to start application "GA.exe", but on start it's taking data from file "acc.txt".
If I start it normallly (via double click :-)) it works, but if I use code below it say "Can't find acc.txt".

My first idea:

```
Process.Start(pathToGA.exe);
```

Second idea:

```
ProcessStartInfo pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    Arguments = FolderWithGA.exePath,
                    FileName = pathToGA.exe,
                };
```

And both don't work.

Answer (score 3):

You should set [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) to the directory that holds `acc.txt` and `GA.exe`:

```
ProcessStartInfo pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Arguments = FolderWithGA.exePath,
    FileName = pathToGA.exe,
    WorkingDirectory = FolderWithGA
};
```